# About speedy mass deletion of users in Kentico10

Tags: kentico

I want to delete more than 1 million User information in Kentico10.

I tried to delete it with UserInfoProvider.DeleteUser (); (see the following documentation), but it is expected that it will take nearly one year with a simple calculation.
https://docs.kentico.com/api10/configuration/users#Users-Deletingauser

Because it's a simple calculation, I think it's actually a bit shorter, but it still takes time.
Is there any other way to delete users in a short time?

Answer (score 1):

Of course make sure you have a backup of your database before you do any of this.

Depending on the features you're using, you could get away with a SQL statement.  Due to the complexities of the references of a user to multiple other tables, the SQL statement can get pretty complex and you need to make sure you remove the other references before removing the actual user record.

I'd highly recommend an API approach and delete users through the API so it removes all the references for you automatically.  In your API calls make sure you wrap the delete action in the following so it stops the logging of the events and other labor-intensive activities not needed.

```
using (var context = new CMSActionContext())
{
    context.DisableAll();
    // delete your user
}
```

In your code, I'd only select the top 100 or so at a time and delete them in batches.  Assuming you don't need this done all in one run, you could let the scheduled task run your custom code for a week and see where you're at.

If all else fails, figure out how to delete the user and the 70+ foreign key references and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you delete them with SQL query? - I believe it will be much faster.

Comment: A SQL query doesn't delete any child or foreign key records.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk delete functionality exist starting from [version 10](http://ideas.kentico.com/forums/239189-kentico-product-ideas/suggestions/5774599-mass-delete-users).

[UserInfoProvider](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/12_0/api/html/T_CMS_Membership_UserInfoProvider.htm) has BulkDelete method. Actually any InfoProvider object  inhereted from AbstractInfoProvider has [BulkDelete](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/12_0/api/html/M_CMS_DataEngine_AbstractInfoProvider_3_BulkDelete.htm) method.

Comment: The bulk delete functionality does not suppress any of the logging that I'm aware of.

Comment: I've never tried it ;) I would test it with with small batch, make sure it's working and then disable all the logging.